# How to extract the right link to the picture from feed API object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

im using the graph API to get feeds , in the feeds i have message , picture key and its value looks like formated link that riderects somehow . 
how can i get this picture ? 
if i have this :

```
  "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBuv4KHE_CDlCPV&w=130&h=130&url=http00253A00252F00252Fi1.ytimg.com00252Fvi00252F8dWcLkK62lM00252Fhqdefault.jpg",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here looks like URL encoded with something like:

```
var uri = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/8dWcLkK62lM/hqdefault.jpg';
encodeURIComponent(uri).replace(/%/g, '0025')
```

You may decode it with:

```
var encodedURI = 'http00253A00252F00252Fi1.ytimg.com00252Fvi00252F8dWcLkK62lM00252Fhqdefault.jpg';
decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(encodedURI.replace(/00/g,'%')))
```

Comment: how did you get the first result? im trying to do this with c++